# Sql Compact edition - simple select statement doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have this really simple trouble I can't seem to overcome.

I'm trying to execute this code lines with sql ce :

```
SqlCeCommand comSelect = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Items WHERE barcode = '@barcode'", conn);
comSelect.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("barcode", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)).Value = barC;
```

For some weird reason - it always comes back as empty- i.e not results found. If I put the parameter value by myself in the query string, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE barcode = '123ABC'
```

then it works perfect. I will add that the column IS a NVarChar.

Any idea of why this isn't working?

Comment: If you put your parameter into single quotes (`'@barcode'`) then it's really a **string literal** - not a parameter anymore. So your SELECT is searching for items where the column `barcode` contains the value `@barcode` - which is obviously not what you want....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Items WHERE barcode = @barcode"
```

Instead of what you have. Please do note the lack of quotes in `@barcode`.

Comment: Thank you !! I geuss that when you declare a parameter as a NVarChar type it puts the quotes there by itself, so when I put it, the statement was : "SELECT...WHERE barcode= ''123ABC''

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Items WHERE barcode = @barcode", conn);
comSelect.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@barcode", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)).Value = barC;
```

Comment: sorry, I missed the lack of quotes. Your answer is good as well